# View NullPointerException Java Android

Tags: java, android, view, nullpointerexception

I have an NullPointerException in Game.java.

This is code from game.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/tile_layout >

    <com.example.myapp.GameView 
        android:id="@+id/tile_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is code from GameView.java

```
public class GameView extends View{

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

.... 

}
```

and this is code from Game.java

```
public class Game extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.game);
  GameView gameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.tile_view);
  ....

}
...
}
```

Why is gameView in Game.java null?

**Answer** : I just forgot write in super second parameter.

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
```

Comment: Use `LayoutInflator` and inflate the view

Comment: Post the stack trace and point out which line in your code is the one the exception is thrown on.

Comment: i added this two lines two Game.java

   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.game,(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tile_layout));
   GameView gameView = (GameView) view.findViewById(R.id.tile_view);

but doesnt help me

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your layout is in game.xml and your game view has id tile_view, then correct one is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
GameView gameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.tile_view);
```

Comment: ok i edited my post, in app it is game.xml and i want get GameView by id

Comment: Ok, then try add a constructor to your GamaeView.java:     public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, it's hard to say for sure, but if you don't call `super.onCreate()` in Game.java, that will result in a NPE. I'd guess that's the issue just in terms of easy things to overlook.

Comment: i call it... watch my Edit